# Symbol mangled with suffix "$UNIX2003", when compiling with proper header included

Tags: c, macos, name-mangling, dlsym, symbol-table

I'd like to find out which symbol is called when my code runs 'system' function.

In my sample code, when the header stdlib.h is specifically included, the symbol is called _system$UNIX2003, and when the header isn't included, there (probably) default symbol named _system (without the suffix $UNIX2003)

The following image shows my experiment results : 
[image]
Why do we have different symbols for system ?
Is there anyway to detect the correct symbol during runtime (I tried with dlsym, but i need handle for containing dynamic library, but couldn't figure out with library should i load with dlopen)  ?

> EDIT : this strange symbol mangling occur to me only when compiling under 32bits arch.
>
> EDIT2: I was suggested to use implicit function pointer to acquire the address of the right symbol. but it won't work unless i specifically call that function in my code. otherwise, I get compilation error of using undeclared identifier 'system'

Comment: `system()`isn't a syscall. It will use one for creating a new process.

Comment: The library is probably just called `libc` as `system()` is part of the C standard. In any case, it is always linked as long as you don't instruct your compiler specifically not to. You should **always** include the header declaring the function you want to use.

Comment: @FelixPalmen, thanks for your comments, I edited my question accordingly. The function I mentioned in my question is 'system' but i referred for the more general case of obtaining symbol name from function during runtime. is there any way I can achieve this goal ?

Comment: Sounds a bit like an *xy-problem* to me. Symbols are used by the (dynamic) linker, so no, at runtime (that is, *after* linking was done), there's no way to access them. What problem are you trying to solve doing this?

Comment: @FelixPalmen, I need this for function hooking. First, i'm trying to apply the method of _dyld_lookup_and_bind (from dylid.h) in order to get the pointer of this symbol. then, I use this pointer to override the function by my own implementation.

Comment: I didn't do this so far, but you will get the pointer of `system()` at runtime by just treating `system` as a pointer. Wouldn't that be enough? If not, suggest to ask specifically about function hooking, there might be someone knowing a good answer.